# Can't Log Out from Lubuntu 15.4

Tags: logout, gnome-session

The log out/shut down button is not responding to clicks. Tried:

`gnome-session-quit`and got:

> ** (gnome-session-quit:1782): WARNING **: Failed to call logout: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command as Normal user not root. this will kill all processes and send you back to login window

```
kill -9 -1
```

> "A PID of -1 is special; it indicates all processes except the kill
>   process itself and init."

Read [this](http://aarklonlinuxinfo.blogspot.com/2008/07/kill-9-1.html) for more info